# array getting pushed elements by ngdocheck multiple times in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to update my empty array 'filelistArray' when content available on 'this.uploaCopy.queue' array, this is happening at multiple times, i mean, the same array getting executed multiple times and 'filelistArray' contains multiple duplicate items.

But, i want to update the array where there is content on 'this.uploaCopy.queue', and only available content, there should not be any duplicate.

Could anyone please help on this?

```
ngDoCheck() {
  if (this.uploadCopy.queue !== undefined && this.uploadCopy.queue.length > 0) {


    for (let entryitemlist of this.uploadCopy.queue) {

      this.filelistArray.push(entryitemlist.file.name);

    }

  }

  if (this.uploadCopy.queue == undefined && this.uploadCopy.queue.length == 0) {
   this.filelistArray.length = 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: Is this.uploadcopyqueue passed as input?

Comment: yes, it is passed as input

Comment: Did this help you? I have edited my ans.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use ngonchanges simple change and check if its current value is there and do the rest. Refer angular docs for ngonchanges. This can help remove duplicates in an Array.

this.newArr = Array.from(new Set(this.oldArr.map((itemInArray) => itemInArray)))